# c# replace null in select linq to array

Tags: c#, linq

```
   var eans = myDeserializedClass.listings
     .Select(x => new {  x.amount, x.variant.variantName ?? " "})
     .Where(x => x.variantName != null)
     .ToArray();
```

Code above don't works.
How can i replace null value  in this case?

```
x.variant.variantName ?? " "
```

When i make ?? "  " there is an error.
[image]

Very similar code with a name of the field (As shown in the image) compiles just fine:

```
   var eans = myDeserializedClass.listings
     .Select(x => new {  x.amount, V = x.variant.variantName ?? " "})
     .Where(x => x.V != null)
     .ToArray();
```

I tried a lot of things and can't find solution to replace null value in this select

classes looks like :

```
   public class Ask888
    {
        public string askId { get; set; }
        public DateTime askCreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime askUpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime askExpiresAt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Listing888
    {
        public string listingId { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string amount { get; set; }
        public string currencyCode { get; set; }
        public string inventoryType { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
        public Product888 product { get; set; }
        public Variant888 variant { get; set; }
        public object batch { get; set; }
        public Ask888 ask { get; set; }
        public object order { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product888
    {
        public string productId { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root888
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public int pageNumber { get; set; }
        public int pageSize { get; set; }
        public bool hasNextPage { get; set; }
        public List<Listing888> listings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Variant888
    {
        public string variantId { get; set; }
        public string variantName { get; set; }
        public string variantValue { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally i did like this  and error all the time ;/

```
string json = response.Content.ToString();
    
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
                };
    
    
Root888 myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root888>(json, settings);
    
    
    
    
var eans = myDeserializedClass.listings
.Select(x => new { x.listingId, x.product.productId, x.status, x.amount, variantName = x.variant.variantName ?? " ", variantId = x.variant.variantId ?? " ", variantValue = x.variant.variantValue ?? " " })
.ToArray();
```

error still
[image]

Comment: I've done (not really recommended) edit that extract compiling version of the statements from the image attached to the post. I'm now quite confused what you have trouble with and so far 2 answers recommend exactly what is shown in the image attached to the post (use name for the field in the anonymous type) which make those answers not exactly useful... Please review my edit and clarify what type of result (presumably not involving naming the field) you are looking for.

Comment: I edited the post and trried what you said .But error is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that variant is null and thus you can't fetch the variant name of the null object

You have the code:

```
var eans = myDeserializedClass.listings
 .Select(x => new {  x.amount, V = x.variant.variantName ?? " "})
 .Where(x => x.V != null)
 .ToArray();
```

This just handles cases where the variantName is null. But what about the parent object that contains the variantName? What if that is null?

Change it to use ?. before variantName. Then if the variant is null then the null propagating operator ?? actually has something usable to work with.

This should work:

```
var eans = myDeserializedClass.listings
 .Select(x => new {  x.amount, V = x.variant?.variantName ?? " "})
 .Where(x => x.V != null)
 .ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to name the member of the anonymous type:

```
var eans = myDeserializedClass.listings
                       .Select(x => new { x.listingId, x.product.productId, x.status, x.amount, variantName = x.variant.variantName ?? " ",x.variant.variantId, x.variant.variantValue }).Where(x => x.variantName != null)
                       .ToArray();
```

Crucial bit:

variantName = x.variant.variantName ?? " "

Comment: I did exacly like you post here but still is there error . Edited main question.

Comment: @Adamszsz Note that this answer was posted long before you had edited your question post to include the _run-time error_. This answer addresses the _compile-time error_, which was the only error in your question post at that time.